# Como quebrar linhas na saída de um Array?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, eu tenho um array no PHP que mostra a data que foi feito o último backup de cada loja, e as informações são mostradas da seguinte maneira:

```
  LOJA01 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 02-01-2017.
  LOJA01 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em3: 30-12-2016.
  LOJA01 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em3: 31-12-2016.
  LOJA03 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 10-12-2016.
  LOJA03 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA03 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.
  LOJA05 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 10-12-2016.
  LOJA05 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA05 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.
  LOJA06 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA06 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA06 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.
```

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma com que a cada loja diferente ele pule uma linha ou separe, notem que cada loja tem o bkp 01, 02 e 03...

A saída que eu gostaria seria algo assim:

```
  LOJA01 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 02-01-2017.
  LOJA01 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em3: 30-12-2016.
  LOJA01 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em3: 31-12-2016.

  LOJA03 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 10-12-2016.
  LOJA03 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA03 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.

  LOJA05 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 10-12-2016.
  LOJA05 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA05 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.

  LOJA06 - Bkp 01 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA06 - Bkp 02 teve o ultimo backup em1: 11-12-2016.
  LOJA06 - Bkp 03 teve o ultimo backup em1: 09-12-2016.
```

O Meu Array está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );
$lista_lojas = array(   
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/01/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/01/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/01/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/03/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/03/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/03/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/05/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/05/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/05/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/06/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/06/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/06/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
);
?>
```

Página que exibe os dados do array:

```
    <?php

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        // Inclui o arquivo com os caminhos dos PLUEAN.BIN 
        include_once('includes/array_servers.php');

        foreach($lista_lojas as $l_nome => $l_caminho) 
        { ?>

        <?php 

            $today = date('d-m-Y'); //recebe a data atual
            $seconds = strtotime($today); //converte para segundos
            $diff_date = date("d-m-Y",($seconds - 345600));
            $data_antiga = "31-12-1969";
            // echo $diff_date;
            $data_mod = date ("d-m-Y", filemtime($l_caminho));
            //echo $data_obsoleta;


                    if (($data_mod <= $diff_date) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt))

                    { ?>
                        <img src="img/down.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em1: " . date ("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
                             echo $lojaAt; echo "<br>"  ;
                    } elseif (($data_mod == $data_antiga) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt))
                    {?>
                        <img src="img/down.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em2: " . date ("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
                            echo $lojaAt; echo "<br>"   ;

                    } elseif (($data_mod >= $diff_date) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt)) 
                    {?>
                        <img src="img/up.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em3: " . date ("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
                            echo $lojaAt; echo "<br>"   ;

                    } else

                    ?> 
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: E o código onde você mostra os itens?

Comment: Está aí em cima!

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria tratar na hora da impressão do valor. +- Assim:

```
<?php


$lista_lojas = array(   
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/01/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/01/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA01 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/01/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/03/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/03/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA03 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/03/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/05/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/05/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA05 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/05/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 01"  => "servers/06/bk001/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 02"  => "servers/06/bk002/Mpcfg.ini",
    "LOJA06 - Bkp 03"  => "servers/06/bk003/Mpcfg.ini",
);

$lojaAnt = '';
foreach($lista_lojas as $key => $item) {

    $lojaAt = explode(' ',$key)[0];                         ;

    if ($lojaAt<>$lojaAnt){
        echo "<br>";
    }

    echo $key."  ".$item."<br>";    
    $lojaAnt=$lojaAt;
}

/*Saída:

LOJA01 - Bkp 01 servers/01/bk001/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA01 - Bkp 02 servers/01/bk002/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA01 - Bkp 03 servers/01/bk003/Mpcfg.ini

LOJA03 - Bkp 01 servers/03/bk001/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA03 - Bkp 02 servers/03/bk002/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA03 - Bkp 03 servers/03/bk003/Mpcfg.ini

LOJA05 - Bkp 01 servers/05/bk001/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA05 - Bkp 02 servers/05/bk002/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA05 - Bkp 03 servers/05/bk003/Mpcfg.ini

LOJA06 - Bkp 01 servers/06/bk001/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA06 - Bkp 02 servers/06/bk002/Mpcfg.ini
LOJA06 - Bkp 03 servers/06/bk003/Mpcfg.ini */
```

Atualização:

Inserido a solução no código que você forneceu:

```
 <?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// Inclui o arquivo com os caminhos dos PLUEAN.BIN 
include_once('includes/array_servers.php');
$lojaAnt = '';
foreach ($lista_lojas as $l_nome => $l_caminho) {
?>

        <?php

    $today       = date('d-m-Y'); //recebe a data atual
    $seconds     = strtotime($today); //converte para segundos
    $diff_date   = date("d-m-Y", ($seconds - 345600));
    $data_antiga = "31-12-1969";
    // echo $diff_date;
    $data_mod    = date("d-m-Y", filemtime($l_caminho));
    //echo $data_obsoleta;

    //$lojaAt = explode(' ',$l_nome)[0];  


    if ($lojaAt <> $lojaAnt) {
        echo "<br>"; //Colocar aqui o código para quebrar a linha
    }

    $lojaAnt = $lojaAt;


    if (($data_mod <= $diff_date) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt)) {
?>
                      <img src="img/down.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php
        echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em1: " . date("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
        echo $lojaAt;
        echo "<br>";
    } elseif (($data_mod == $data_antiga) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt)) {
?>
                      <img src="img/down.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php
        echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em2: " . date("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
        echo $lojaAt;
        echo "<br>";

    } elseif (($data_mod >= $diff_date) and ($lojaAt == $lojaAt)) {
?>
                      <img src="img/up.png" width="15" height="15"/>&nbsp;
                            <?php
        echo "$l_nome teve o ultimo backup em3: " . date("d-m-Y.", filemtime($l_caminho));
        echo $lojaAt;
        echo "<br>";

    } else
?> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mau humor... me deu uma luz, mas o problema que eu esbarrei é que eu uso uma estrutura de if pra calcular umas datas lá... e quando eu coloco o seu script para essa estrutura ele não funciona,... lá em cima eu postei meu arquivo de saída para caso vc possa me dar uma ajuda! um grande abraço.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Não entendi a diferença da exibição em cada IF? "em1", "em2" e "em3" difere em algo? ou você colocou apenas para teste? Por que a exibição ocorre da mesma forma para todos. Nesse caso seria melhor utilizar o operador OR ou || e utilizar um IF apenas.

Comment: Foi pra teste, apenas pra saber em qual ele estava entrando!

Comment: Não consigo testar teu código, pois tem include e uso de funções não fornecidas. Aquele último else? Será executado alguma vez?

Comment: não... ele não é executado!

Comment: Então, qual é o problema? não é só botar a quebra de linha depois desse if? Vou editar a resposta ai então você testa.

Comment: Resposta editada. Da uma olhada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51139/discussion-between-mau-humor-and-igor-santana).

Comment: Mau humor, eu colei o código da forma que você postou, mas não funcionou ele saiu um em baixo do outro sem quebrar linha, eu acho que pode ser algo relacionado a estrutura de IF, uma vez que sem IF ele funciona...

Comment: Verificou se ele está imprimindo o `<br>` correspondente? pode ser que você precisa utilizar outro recurso para o espaçamento, já que pelo visto você está utilizando imagem. tenta algo como `<div style="margin-bottom:20px"></div>` no lugar de `<br>`.

Comment: agora ele só aumentou o espaçamento! será que esses IF estão atrapalhando? vou testar usar <font color> no lugar de imagens

Comment: Mas você disse que o espaçamento não funciona?

Comment: Sem um código que eu possa testar, fica difícil te ajudar.

Comment: amigo, eu postei umas respostas no chat... se eu tiro o if e coloco na sua estrutura funciona de boa! mas quando eu começo a usar o if para usar as imagens ele para de funcionar... vou postar o código no chat